# Phonegap when app is loaded completly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to make a battery app that animates the battery level from 0% to the current level as an animation with Jquery.

It is working, BUT.. when my app is loaded, after the splash screen is done, and cordova has loaded aswell, the animation is almost finished.  The only reason that i know this is because i set the animation to 5 seconds.

I want to make it so that, the animtion starts when the app is loaded.

I am not sure if this "state" im refering to has a direct event name or so.  So i am sorry if i am unable to describe it with the real words.  :-)

Consider the following piece of code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
}

function onBatteryStatus(info) {
  $("div#status").animate({ width: bat + "%" }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using the PhoneGap Splashscreen functionality :

[PhoneGap Splash Screen API Doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen)

You should call your splash screen on the Java side of things (DroidGap) and let PhoneGap do it's own job in the background while the Splash screen is being displayed. This blogpost which includes relevant code should help you with your problem :

[Splash Screens in PhoneGap](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ie/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html)

What should now happen is PhoneGap will load and then your splash screen will be displayed in full. Hope this fixes your problem!!

Comment: Do you mean wrap document.ready around my jquery div#status call?   If so i already tried that :-)

Comment: Oh cool, so your main problem is PhoneGaps onDeviceReady is firing too early?

Comment: Yea i guess thats it.  My animation fires off before i can see it, so just because i choose 5 seconds i do only see like 500 mili seconds.  Like the last of it.

Comment: Do you know a solution? :-)

Comment: I might actually, see the revised answer above

Comment: Great! Let me know how it goes - I think it should fix your problem

Comment: that totally worked from what i can see.  I see the animation now, its showing itself from the start.  Well thats great, thanks a lot for the links and the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are going in the right directions from what i can see. Here's how my base Cordova project is uaully setup.

**Javascript**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// `load`, `deviceready`, `offline`, and `online`.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of `this` is the event. In order to call the `receivedEvent`
// function, we must explicity call `app.receivedEvent(...);`
onDeviceReady: function() {
    // Get battery status HERE
}
};
```

And then in my "index.html" i initialize my app class like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
```

Comment: Nice, i am going to look at it laters, i am about to travel home now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [cordova-jquerymobile-boilerplate](https://github.com/sebbie1o1/cordova-jquerymobile-boilerplate). You should start your work with a boilerplate, it will make you go fast and safe.